# My jquery animate code is not working

Tags: jquery, css

Here is my code for the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    &("#slider .slides").animate({marginLeft: "-720px"});

});
```

Comment: Use $ instead of &

Comment: is it the typo `&` instead of `$` in your selector class? You would be getting a js console error message if this was the case. Probably something like `& is not a function` or `Unexpected token &`

Comment: Ah yes sorry - i fixed that...however my code still isn't functioning. Any other possible suggestions?

Comment: @KamThomas Did you add jQuery UI...?

Comment: add this  ```<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>``` at the top of your code.

Comment: Oh thank  you - I'm brand new and didn't realize this was a necessity... guess i should have done my homework instead of jumping straight in. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

please change

& with $

and also youre selector

## slider .slides

so the transition will take effect on your slide class

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.use jquery's `find()` method inside your id.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#slider").find(".slides").animate({marginLeft: "-720px"});

});
```

```css
.slides {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 500px;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
<div class="slides">

</div>
</div>
```

FIddle https://jsfiddle.net/wu4oe7k7/